# Cassandra data model design approach

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.1

I am new Cassandra. please help me to understand how to define best data model in Cassandra.

***Model 1:***

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    username text,
    email text,
    age int
)

CREATE TABLE users_by_username (
    username text PRIMARY KEY,
    id uuid
)

CREATE TABLE users_by_email (
    email text PRIMARY KEY,
    id uuid
)
```

> Advantages

:
        1.No duplicate records.
        2. Update/Delete only once , But to find user details need one select
            query.

> Dis Advantages

```
    1.  To get user records, Need to select in 2 tables (  users_by_username   
         or users_by_email and users )
```

***Model 2***:

```
 CREATE TABLE users_by_username (
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    username text,
    email text,
    age int
)

  CREATE TABLE users_by_email (
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    username text,
    email text,
    age int
)
```

> Advantages:

```
  1.  To get user records, only once select query.
```

> Dis Advantages:

```
    1.Duplicate records in two tables.
    2. Update/Delete needs to performed in two tables.
```

Please suggest me which model will be good ?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to model tables (column families) is to define first how are you going to access the information:
- are you going to query by uuid, email, username? your examples would work fine only if you will be looking by uuid (primary key)

Comment: query by email for one use case and query by username for another use case

Comment: In that case, you will need 2 tables:
` CREATE TABLE users_by_username (
    id uuid,
    username text,
    email text,
    age int,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, username)
)`

  `CREATE TABLE users_by_email (
    id uuid,
    username text,
    email text,
    age int,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, email)
)`

When doing inserts, updates or deletes you would need to use atomic [updates](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/batch_r.html)

`BEGIN UNLOGGED  BATCH
  INSERT INTO users_by_username VALUES (...);
  INSERT INTO users_by_email VALUES (...);
APPLY BATCH;`

Comment: Thanks. it will be helpful